# how to show text on selected slices only in pie chart using iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart, ios-charts

I need to draw a pie chart where on selection a label appears on the slice showing percentage. I am using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library. but I didn't find out any way to stop showing the text on slice unless it was selected slice. Any help will be appreciated.